# Node.js - cannot fild module 'upper-case'

Tags: node.js

i'm following the tutorials on W3schools but i've hit an error - cannot find module 'upper-case': https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_npm.asp

[image]

I installed the package and can see it located here:

M:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\upper-case

[image]

Using Windows 10

Comment: Try to install upper-case package in your local projectfolder and try to execute it. If its working fine then your global link has problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the dependency in your project, go into your project root folder and run `npm i upper-case --save` this will add the dependency into your package.json file

Comment: Thanks, the package installed in the project root folder and now works ok